# How can i prevent a tensorflow model from giving me inf as a loss value whilst training with more than 17 data pairs

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I am attempting to train a prediction model that, for an input x predicts the output x^2. I am fairly new to ai and trying around with a few things like this. whilst using xs and ys with a length below 18, everything works fine, but as soon as the lenght is >= 18, the loss value first starts getting extremely high and eventually, after 3 or 4 epochs, reaches infinite, which results in the prediction result beeing null aswell.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras


def quadratVonX(y_new):
    xs = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30], dtype=float)
    ys = np.array([0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361, 400, 441, 484, 529, 576, 625, 676, 729, 784, 841, 900], dtype=float)
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1])])

    model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
    model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=50)
    return model.predict(y_new)[0]


prediction = quadratVonX([15])
print(prediction)
```

sample output of one of the epochs:

```
Epoch 50/50
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: inf
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 58ms/step
[-inf]
```

I was expecting to not get a negative / not existing result, like i do when i use xs and ys with a length below 18.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the learning rate is too high. The [default for SGD](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/experimental/SGD) is 0.01. I tried your example with a learning rate of 0.001 and it converged.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def quadratVonX(y_new):
    xs = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30], dtype=float)
    ys = np.array([0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361, 400, 441, 484, 529, 576, 625, 676, 729, 784, 841, 900], dtype=float)
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=(1,))])

    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001), loss='mean_squared_error')
    model.summary()
    model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=50)
    return model.predict(y_new)

prediction = quadratVonX([15])
print(prediction)
```

Results in:

```
Epoch 50/50
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 948us/step - loss: 10422.5850
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 35ms/step
[[342.24048]]
```